# Can we use SSIS to parse data from application before we store in db...?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ssis

Exploring the feasibility of something here... We have a UI page in the mvc3 web-application that the admin will use to upload a 'csv' file. Is it possible to have an SSIS package that will be called by the application..that will validate/transform all these data and store into db if its all valid or throw back error details to application if there are invalid data?

Just trying to leverage the capabilities of SSIS to do the parsing of file and transformation of data. If this is not possible, is there a better way?

Please provide your thought..much appreciated!

**update:** yes, need to execute ssis on the fly.. and give back a message on the UI page ..telling the 'uploader' if his upload failed or not based on message that SSIS would give back to the application.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call SSIS from the web page, while the web page is running?

Comment: @John: Hillary explained in a comment to my answer that indeed they want real-time error information to be returned back to the user who uploaded the file. That's what "throw back error details" means...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use SSIS to parse a text file. You could also use a sledgehammer to drive finishing nails. Better bet would be something like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.com/) to keep you out of the text-parsing mud of parsing the text file yourself.

---

Given the edits and debate, I'll elaborate a bit. Mainly that there are a few big problems I see calling SSIS directly from your MVC controller:

a) Massive external dependency to ship around. Your dev, CI and staging environments will need full blown SQL server with SSIS enabled and probably a slew of other configuration depending on implementation details.

b) Speed -- SSIS is a big job engine, takes a while to spin up before it even starts working.

c) Messaging -- if the point of the operation is letting a user know what is wrong, SSIS is the wrong tool. Unless you want to write a tool to translate SSIS import errors into readable English. Then you should probably stop whatever it is you are doing and sell that tool rather than solving this problem.

On the flip side, most of the .NET based file parsing stuff and C# give you plenty of error handling capabilities that give you a much better shot of getting an understandable error message to a user quickly.

Finally, if you are looking at large files here, you really need to think about some sort of queuing and messaging system. In that context, SSIS could make a bit more sense though I still think the error messages border on useless.

Comment: @Paul: So you are saying it is a good idea to try and mount SSIS within a web application and then to capture the error output when you could have some nice, clean, not SQL-Server dependant code do it for you?

Comment: @Wyatt: What do you mean by "mount SSIS"? SSIS is a tool available in the SQL Server products family... You don't mount it. You specify an SSIS package and then execute it.

Comment: -1: please explain the "mud". SSIS handles CSV files trivially.

Comment: @Paul: I mean you are calling SSIS from within your MVC web page controller. Versus using some native C# code to parse the file on the spot.

Comment: @John Saunders: mud meaning parsing your own CSV files, he sounds like someone who only knows of SSIS as the way to get a CSV into SQL Server.

Comment: @Wyatt: I would call it triggering an SSIS package and believe it's cleaner than and more decoupled than writing C# code to handle the file parsing and loading. I'm a big C# and .NET fan but when I see a usecase where the db and its associated tools are a better fit for the job then I use that technology instead.

Comment: @Wyatt: ok, I thought you were implying this is difficult to do with SSIS.

Comment: @wyatt, @paul..we have to do lot of transformations + put data into different tables.. moreover figuring out if SSIS way is easier than writing c# code..

Comment: @john yes, need to execute ssis on the fly.. and give back a message on the UI page ..telling the user if his upload failed or not

Comment: i open up my bids..and i check the 'data sources'.. all i see is 'flatfile', 'excel file', 'xml source', 'raw file source', 'ado.net'

Comment: @Wyatt, John & Hillary: I added a note about using SQL Server Agent to handle uploaded CSV files in my answer. This is a method that would not require any code changes at all except adding the file upload capability to the application.

Comment: @paul thx Paul..but If I use.. sql server agent-- I can't return a real-time error/success message to the user.. That's reqd here since we have to prompt him to correct the file and upload again

Comment: Edited and elaborated on the answer a bit.

Comment: @Wyatt: Per better explanation of the process from the OP I'm rescinding my downvote. And i'm not an SSIS head, lol. My top two tags are C# and .NET. My understanding of the requirement was that it was fairly standard ETL and not a method for bridging for a real-time ETL process...

Comment: @Paul: No sweat, your answer definitely was valid if it was an old-fashioned ETL scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly an SSIS package can do that, that sort of thing is its purpose. It's easier of course if you have an experienced SSIS developer as SSIS can be quite daunting.  You can create logging inthe package and exception tables to throw out the bad records and then after the process is complete, check the logs/exception tables to return any bad records to the user who kicked off the process. We have a database that stores meta data about each time an SSISI pacakage is run and you might need that too in order to be able to determin if the error record relate to the file that user uploaded or someone else's being run at about the same time.

Comment: the whole point is how can I get my web-application to talk to SSIS package on the go, pass the file or output back an error or success message?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a fairly standard [ETL procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) and that is exactly what SSIS was designed for. SSIS will indeed read CSV files and be able to perform validation on individual fields. What you do with the result of that validation (good or bad, pass no pass) is entirely up to you.

And yes, you can fire off SSIS packages on the fly... as necessary. Check out the [dtexec utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx?ppud=4). You could also set up a SQL Server Agent job which would monitor the folder that receives the uploaded CSV files and trips off the SSIS processes against them automatically. You ASP.NET code only have to worry about the upload. Everything else would then be a SQL Server/SQL Agent-based ETL operation.

Comment: the whole point is how can I get my web-application to talk to SSIS package on the go, pass the file or output back an error or success message?

Comment: If I use.. sql server agent-- I can't return a real-time error/success message to the user.. That's reqd here since we have to prompt him to correct the file and upload again..

Comment: lol. ok. I didn't understand what you meant by "throw back." In this case, if you want real-time error info then C# is definitely the better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute SSIS packages from code.  We have a similar process of users uploading CSV files to execute a package but the package is doing a lot more than just validating/parsing logic.

If it's just a little validation and parsing logic then take a look at [Rhino ETL](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx) and FileHelpers.  In fact, for us, these two tools are compelling enough that we are considering using this period but we have don't have a lot of SSIS packages, a dedicated SSIS resource and most of our packages are simple.  [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) alone is a great tool if it's really simple parsing.

Here's some articles on Rhino ETL.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ETLWithCSharp.aspx

https://github.com/ayende/rhino-etl

If you want to execute an SSIS package you will want to look into the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.aspx) namespace.

[Here's an article on executing SSIS from c#.](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article795-how-to-execute-ssis-packages-in-csharp-aspnet-part-ii-.aspx)